# "Овець", "вівець", "вівць" чи "вівців"?

Tags: відмінювання, іменники, чергування

Якою є усталена форма родового відмінку множини до слова *«вівця»*?

Пономарів [пропонує](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-40640475) тезу, що `в-` є протетичним звуком, що є цілком очікувано. Але ніц не каже про відмінювання.

Різні джерела дають суперечливі пропозиції:

- **овець** — [Словник.ua](http://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%C2%B2%C2%D6%DF);
- > Іменник *вівця* в родовому відмінку множини має форму **овець**

  — сайт, який називає себе [«Офіційний сайт української мови»](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/morfologija_i_pravopis/vidminjuvannja_imennikiv_i_vidmini/6-1-0-94) і знаходиться на Росії;
- **Вівців** (діалектне) = овець (усталене) — ще один [«словник діалектних слів»](http://proridne.org/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2/) (теж сайт чомусь на Росії)
- Ґуґлопошук дає ["овець" 413k](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q="%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C"), ["вівець" 4k](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q="%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C"), ["вівць" 4.5k](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q="%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%86%D1%8C"), ["вівців" 12.5k](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q="%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B2");
- Деякі сайти використовують декілька варіантів, подеколи навіть в одній і тій само статті:

  > Вчені з Кембриджського університету навчили **овець** відрізняти обличчя людей.
  >   Таким чином, вчені довели, що мозок **вівць** розвинутий на рівні з мавпами — [Agro News](http://www.agronews.ua/node/84673)

Запитую тому, що на мій особистий смак *«вівць»* та *«вівців»* звучить краще, але суперечить результатам пошуку по інтернету.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

СУМ у прикладах подає форму ***овець***

> [Вівця](http://sum.in.ua/s/vivcja), і, жін.
>   1. Невелика свійська тварина, яка дає вовну, м'ясо, молоко; самка барана. <...> *Отари **овець** сунуться по степу, неначе білі та
>   чорні хмари* (Нечуй-Левицький, III, 1956, 314); <...>

Окрім того, прикметник до *вівця* - *овечий*.

> [Овечий](http://sum.in.ua/s/ovechyj), а, е.
>   1. Прикм. до *вівця*. *Відоллються вовку **овечі** слізки* (Номис, 1864, № 4099); <...>  //  Який складається з *овець*. *На вільний
>   степ, як хмара з-поза хмари, Без ліку йшло овечої отари* (Яків
>   Щоголів, Поезії, 1958, 167);<...>

[Український правопис](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par8) пояснює це **чергуванням голосних**, зокрема:

> § 8.1.: У сучасній українській мові звуки **`о`, `е`** (у відкритих
>   складах) часто чергуються з **`і`** (в закритих складах):
>
> а) при словозміні:
>
> <...> 5) *вівса — овес*, *вівця — овець*, *вісь — осі*; <...>

Професор Ющук І.П. у [Практикумі з правопису і граматики української мови](https://ushchuk.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/d196.pdf) наводить цю ж форму, щоправда, як приклад до правила про закінчення іменників І відміни у родовому відмінку множини (§ 58 частина 3):

> <...> в) **слово *вівця* має форму *овець***, *дошка — дощок*,
>   *зморшка — зморщок*, *гра — ігор*; <...>