# "Одразу" і "відразу"

Tags: вибір-слова

Я не мовознавець. Звичайна людина. Я прийшов сюди, бо мене не влаштовує новомодне "одразу". Це полонізм. Я не вірю тим, хто каже, що це українська архаїчна форма. Архаїчна, але настільки архаїчна, що українською вважатися, на мою думку, не може. Така фонетична форма суперечить нормам української мови. Це ріже вухо, мені це звучить штучно. Мені здається, так кажуть лише в селах на Галичині, які зазнали сильної полонізації.

Comment: Вітаємо на Ukrainian.SE! На цьому сайті можна ставити питання й отримувати на них відповіді. Я даю вам шанс поставити питання, базуючись на хоча би якихось джерелах. Ви можете це зробити, натиснувши edit під вашим текстом.

Comment: @P.Vowk, натомість пропоную вам (на правах модератора) відредагувати це запитання, щоб прибрати звідси емоційні вислови «бісить», «брешуть», «ріже вухо» тощо. Запитання має бути об'єктивним і запрошувати до об'єктивних відповідей. Воно не зобов'язане містити посилання, хоча зобов'язане продемонструвати спробу самостійного пошуку відповіді.

Comment: @bytebuster спробував трохи змінити, але мені однаково виглядає як кандидат на видалення, навіть після мого редагування. Мінус на питанні мій, адже воно не дотягує станом на зараз до прийнятного на нашому сайті рівня дискусії.

Comment: @P.Vowk емм, не згоден. Мені здається, що запитання про «одразу-відразу» може отримати товстий трафік, як [«овець»](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/2848/8), бо багато хто з україномовних не відчувають користі від української протези. Авжеж, якщо гарно відредагувати.

Comment: @stegetsj але ж шкода відповіді. Може створити ще одне більш загальне, а з цього поставити *див. також*?

Comment: @stegetsj, можливо, що й так. Проблема цього сайту в тім, що ідей — багато, а виконавців — мало. Створення канонічних запитань (або канонізація наявних) — це складна задача, але вона під силу модераторам і high-rep users. На жаль, вони цим не займаються. Тут же у цій гілці мав бесіду з P.Vowk, але, на жаль, він видалив мої думки з цього приводу. Певно, він вирішив, що я свої коментарі писав особисто йому, а не для всіх.

Comment: @bytebuster хіба необхідно мати права модератора, щоб відредагувати запитання?

Comment: Мене особисто обурює трішки інше: коли кажуть, мовляв, слово _відразу_ двозначне (прислівник зі значенням «зараз же» і давальний відмінок іменника _відраза_ у значенні «огида»), а _одразу_ допомагає усувати цю неоднозначність. На мій погляд, це просто фонетичні форми, що є повними синонімами в обох значеннях (прислівник і давальний відмінок відповідного іменника).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question

Comment: Перестворив: [Префікси і прийменники _од-_ і _від-_](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/7127/585)

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю, як на Галичині, але в селах навколо Києва геть поширене використання *од* замість *від*, чув з дитинства. Наприклад: *одійди*, *одвернутися* тощо. А от в галичан я такого не чув.

І, так, це дійсно архаїчна форма, що прекрасно збереглася, є [в купі](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%9E%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) українських словників, втч. згадано в Грінченка.

Більше можна подивитися чи послухати приклади в відео Ідеї Олександрівни [«Українські діалекти: середньонаддніпрянський»](//youtu.be/2pjRBcqnv6E?t=805) від 13:25.

Comment: Вітаю на цьому сайті. Поясніть, будь ласка, чому ви використовуєте r2u, московсько-український словник-перекладач? Чому, наприклад, не з монгольської чи з гінді? Дякую.

Comment: @bytebuster підозрюю, тому, що там швидко видаються Кримський із Єфремовим і Грінченко, які серед користувачів Ukrainian.SE наче вважаються поважними джерелами.

Comment: @bytebuster тому що з монгольської чи з гінді нема або є, але дуже маленькі.

Comment: У Грінченка немає жодного "одразу". Тому що визнати широко представлене існування в українській літературній мові префікса "од" для такої людини як Грінченко було непросто. І він власне цього не зробив. Проблема, розумієте, існує. Це польська фонетична норма, яка чомусь пролізла в наші ЗМІ. Od razu - це полонізм. Він міг широко існувати, наприклад, і на Поділлі. Спочатку пролізло слово "неодмінно", яке порушило фонетичні норми. Після цьо

Answer (score 1):

Це не зовсім відповідь на запитання, але цікаво, що [Іван Нечуй-Левицький](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B9-%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) у творі [«Криве дзеркало української мови»](https://uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%96_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8) (1912), навпаки, обурювався поширенням форми *від* у тогочасній літературі. Форму *від* (на відміну від *од*) він вважав суто галицькою, не притаманною наддніпрянським діалектам.

> …Шановна авторка певно й не читала статтів небіжчика Грінченка, як треба витовмачувать для народа кожну думку, кожну мисль, навить слова, за котрі селяни не знають і навить втямку не мають. Мова в усіх йіі писаннях, загалом сказавши, мішана, нечиста, білше галицька, ніж украінська, очевидячки тенденційна, партійна, як мова д. Шерстюка і К°, ще й до того вона с самого початку, вже давно нащось уподобала галицьке слово **від**, покинувши украінське — **од**, і через це позатулювала украінські слова, неначе заслонкою навить в своі „Географіі" для народа. Само по собі вона неповинна б і братись писать книжки для украінського народа та для украінських дітей…
>
> …Усі форми слів та падіжів — не украінські: скрізь бачимо галицькі форми, неначе якісь чужоземські: сей (цей), **від (од)**, засіданє, жите, в житю, видань, відродженя, (одродіння) молять ся, окремо, окремий, пишуть ся; і цім стародавнім не народнім хамлом закидана уся книжечка, і само по собі це все буде стоять селянам (та й не селянам!) на заваді при читанні статтів, гарних здебілшого на зміст…
>
> …Якби автор покинув оті польські й галицькі відсотки і взаємини, та написав натомісць слово проценти, відомі навить кожному украінському селянинові, та ще й не ставив приставки — **від**, а поставив **од**, то може можна було б стямкувать за дещо, або принаймні догадатись, за що буде мова в статті, написані доволі чистою украінською мовою, навить з уживанням скрізь украінського **од**, а не **від**, которий дуже ганжує неологізми для читальників…
>
> …Але такі галицькі слівця, як — **від**, **від**роджене, **від**-віт, **від**діл, відчувати, житє, питань, обновлень (!), загострень, діткливо, відомостей, питєм, віттак, прецінь, відтам і т. д. — зовсім таки не належяться до правопису: це зовсім опрічні, инчі од украінських, наче взяті з инчоі славянськоі мови слова, бо в нас вони виходять зовсім инакше: **од**, **од**родіння, **од**віт (відвіт), **од**діл, почувать, життя, питаннів, поновліннів, відомостів, і т. д…
>
> …А наша публіка тепер як купує будлі-яку украінську книжку, то передніше розгортає йіі, переглядає, читає, і як книжка буде галицька, то кидає набік, бо с кількох фраз, навить як углядить — **від**, одразу постерегає, якого вона печева, бо за тим — **від** піде низка галицьких слів…

І, що цікаво, він апелював до того самого Грінченка, до якого апелює (в коментарях) автор запитання.

Answer (score -2):

Я - за "одразу". Бо "відразу" має аналогічну відмінкову форму слова "відраза". Для мене це є важливим чинником та міркуванням недвозначного різноманіття української мови, до того ж я не є заангажованим місцевими говірками.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до цього сайту! Відповіді повинні бути об'єктивними. Особиста думка одного конкретного користувача — це добре, але вона не повинна бути єдиним, що містить допис. Найкраще, якщо така думка підтверджена поважними джерелами, словниками тощо. Тільки таким чином можна відрізнити якісну відповідь від неякісної. Окрім того, двозначність *відраза/огида* вже обговорені у коментарях під запитанням. Ви правильно робите, що оформлюєте думки з коментарів у вигляді відповідей, але давайте робити це сумлінно і якісно.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/3684)